# dismissing a view controller and presenting another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my application, I have 4 `UIViewcontrollers` - A, B, C and D.

From my `UIViewController A`, UIVIewControllers B or C or D can be presented. Suppose, from A, i have presented B. Then, on B, there is are two `UIButtons`, clicking on which, i need to dismiss B and Present C or dismiss B and Present D. This is happening successfully, but first, after dismissing B, the screen of A comes, and then it goes to C or D.

Here's what i did:

On Button Press On B, the action is:

```
{
    UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
    NSLog(@"%@",[controller parentViewController]);
    UITabBarController *tabBarReference = (UITabBarController *)[controller parentViewController];

    HomePageViewController *presController = (HomePageViewController *)tabBarReference.presentingViewController;
    [presController dismissTabControllerWithHandlerWithSenderAtIndex:1];
}
```

In A, i have these methods:

```
-(void)dismissTabControllerWithHandlerWithSenderAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if(index == 0)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

            [self aboutButtonPressed:self];

        }];
    }

    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

            [self settingsButtonPressed:self];

        }];
    }
}
```

Here's the method i am calling..

```
- (IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.contactUsView setHidden:YES];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *deviceType = [prefs objectForKey:@"DeviceType"];
    NSString *iOSType = [prefs objectForKey:@"iOSType"];

    if([iOSType isEqualToString:@"iOS7"])
    {
        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
        {
            SettingsViewController *settingsPage = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iPad" bundle:NULL];
            settingsPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
            [self presentViewController:settingsPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }

        else
        {
            SettingsViewController *settingsPage = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:NULL];
            settingsPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
            [self presentViewController:settingsPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
        {
            SettingsViewController *settingsPage = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iPad_iOS6" bundle:NULL];
            settingsPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
            [self presentViewController:settingsPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }

        else
        {
            SettingsViewController *settingsPage = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iOS6" bundle:NULL];
            settingsPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
            [self presentViewController:settingsPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you dismissing the controllers first & then displaying the next controller?

Comment: yes.. i need to do this.. as when C or D is presented, the B should not be in memory. This is because only A can present B, C or D

Comment: problem is you are using completion block to display the contents!!

Comment: if i do not us ethe completion block, the next view controller is not called.. no matter what i do !!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes:-

Suppose `viewcontroller` A is the base & it `presents` either `view controllers` B or C.

Implement delegate/notifications where the view controller B or C has to be dismissed.

After sending the delegate or posting the notification, dismiss the current `view controller without animation, i.e animation:NO`.

This notification that was posted needs to be heard in `view controller` A.

Here you present the next view controller.

**EDIT:-**

```
-(void)dismissTabControllerWithHandlerWithSenderAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if(index == 0)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self aboutButtonPressed:self];

    }

    else
    {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self settingsButtonPressed:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i did that only.. still A is visible first, then the next view controller is pushed in..

Comment: Nop.. does not work.. the next view controller is not presented, only the current one is dismissed..

Comment: made a small tweak in code!! Check it out!! Calling the dismiss before presenting!!

Comment: Why is your settings button pressed taking "self" object? Isn't the method implemented in the same card?

Comment: it is because the settings button is present in xib. so while creating the IBAction, the argument came automatically. However, it does not make any difference coz i am not doing anything with the argument.